# Angular daterangepicker not working inside a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog, bootstrap-daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I am using [angular-daterangepicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker/) which depends on [bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker):

```
<input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="ctrl.schedule.date" />
```

It is working fine other pages except for inside a modal, more precisely inside an [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog).

It is giving this error:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: el.daterangepicker is not a function
```

It looks as if `bootstrap-daterangepicker` file was not included in the html.

I suspect that when a modal opens bootstrap-daterangepicker is kind of "losing" its effect.

What could be the problem?

Is there any way to *restart* `bootstrap-daterangepicker`?

Comment: just a reminder if its injected in your module?

Comment: @XDProgrammer, yes! I tested on other pages and it is working

Comment: are u using the modal ui.bootstrap or just plain bootstrap modal

Comment: @XDProgrammer I am using ngDialog